# Property of monotone operator (Positive definite)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, monotone-operator-theory

I would like to prove this statement:

"$F$ is monotone if and only if $\nabla  F$ is positive semidefinite."

I only know $F$ is monotone with respect to $\Omega$ if and only if

$$(u-v)^{T}(F(u)-F(v)) \geq 0, \forall u, v \in \Omega.$$

Should I start with $x^{T} \nabla F x$ and then arrive at this stuff is larger or equal to 0?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. $F$ is assumed to be differentiable in the context.

Comment: An equivalent statement is $w^T (F(v+w) - F(v)) \ge 0 \,\forall u,w$. Now write this as $w^T (F(v+ t w) - F(v)) \ge 0 \, \forall u,w \, \forall t \ge 0$. Then compute the derivative with respect to $t$ and play with the result.

Comment: What if the operator is not differentiable? e.g. $F(x)=\max\{x,2x\}$

Comment: Please clarify the differentiability assumption on $F$.

Comment: I can't make sense of this question. Is F real valued and where is it defined? If it is real valued, what should it mean that its gradient is positive definite? I would agree on "If F is convex then it's gradient is monotone."

Comment: @Dirk, I think it's safe to assume from context that $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, so $\nabla F$ is $n\times n$. The gradient of a differentiable convex function is an example of a monotone operator. Of course, monotone operators are more general than this, which was the point of my comment.

Comment: Ah, got it.  To be precise, the question is whether $\nabla F(x) $ is spd for every $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "positive semidefinite". Some people require the matrix to be symmetric others don't. The following is true:

**Theorem.** $F$ is monotone if and only if the *symmetric part* of the Jacobian $\nabla F(x)$ is positive semidefinite for all $x$.

An example could be the rotator by $\pi/2$ in the Euclidean plane.
This is a skew operator with symmetric part being the zero matrix.

For a proof of the characterization theorem, see the book *Variational Analysis* by Rockafellar and Wets, Proposition 12.3.